# I curious of what's different this two linux command

Tags: operating-system

I'm curious to know the difference between these two cat commands in linux:

```
cat ./boot.bin ./kernel.bin /dev/zero | dd bs=512 count=2880 of=devos.img
```

and

```
cat ./boot.bin ./kernel.bin > devos.img
```

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general OS or computer support. More information is available in the [help]. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion
and thank you so much.